# RatingBar displays incorrectly in Android when on same TableRow as TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've got an Android 1.6 activity using a TableLayout. One of the rows has a RatingBar in. This is my xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="name"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="@+id/name"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>  
        <TextView android:text="tags"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tags"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <RatingBar android:id="@+id/rating"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:rating="4"
        android:numStars="5"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="long string"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="this is a very very very long string"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
    </TableRow>

...
</TableLayout>
```

I wanted to put a text label at the left of the table row, then have a 5 star ratings bar on the right. But when I do this, the rating value displays wrongly, and I have lots of spurious empty stars above the specified maximum of 5:

[image]

If I take out the 'rating' TextView, so the RatingBar is on its own table row, the RatingBar displays as expected, showing 4 out of 5 possible stars:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea if it's possible to have a RatingBar on the same row as a TextView? Or do I need to rethink this layout?

edited to add: I think another row in the table which displays a long text string is causing the problem. Without the 'long string' row in the example above, the RatingBar displays correctly in the same row as the 'rating' text.

Comment: This works fine for me on a 1.6 emulator with the TableLayout as the root view and set to FILL_PARENT.

Comment: ah. I've realised that it is another row in the table that is causing the problem. The other row contains a long text string, which appears to be pushing the size of the table cell out so that the ratingbar displays incorrectly. I'll amend my code snippet to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it!

I just needed to set a max width on the 'long string' column, ie.

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="long string"
        android:padding="3dip"/>
    <TextView android:text="this is a very very very long string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="100dip"
        android:padding="3dip"/>
</TableRow>
```

I guess the RatingBar needs to have its space limited in a table cell - if it is given too much room by another component, it will expand to fill it, with unexpected consequences.

Comment: This is the actual reason. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason that the star rating maybe changing size is due to the way that the TableRow expands automatically to fit its parent (in relationship to its neighboring table rows)

You haven't shown in your question your TableLayout element, so you might want to add that if the following doesn't help you solve your problem.

In the TableLayout you can specify the shrink and stretch Columns elements. You list the column index you want to either shrink or expand. The first column being index 0.

```
<TableLayout android:shrinkColumns="1,0" android:stretchColumns="0,1"></TableLayout>
```

You don't need to have both properties listed and its probably easier to experiment with these to work out what works for you. Just be aware that if you stretch columns, i think they stretch to match the parent, in which case you might find a column disappears.

I think you will want to shrink the 2nd column with your star rating within it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course your issue could be a bug in the rating component, which would suck.

Comment: couldn't get this to work btw, tried shrinking the second column, and playing around with all combinations of stretching and shrinking columns but the issue persists :(